# Rails Devise, how to unencrypt a password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

in rails 3 devise, a user record has an  encrypted_password and a password_salt.

How in the console, can I obtain a user's password? How to unencrypt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Devise by default uses the BCrypt algorithm, which AFAIK is not decrypt-able. If you need to be able to decrypt passwords, you need to use a different algorithm such as the [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

There is a [gem](https://github.com/chicks/devise_aes_encryptable) which extends AES support for Devise.

**Note: I have answered this question in a purely academic interest. It would be recommended you continue to use BCrypt. I encourage you to exercise severe caution, since managing passwords is risky business.**

Comment: One should, simply, and very lightly emphasized never, ever — I repeat, never ever decrypt a users password! Just like you don't decrypt the users credit card information. You simply supply a method for them, themselves to reset it.

Comment: @Ekampp well when you need the password to interact with an external service like IMAP, then you will have a problem without decryption. Of course, the solution could be using oath2 authentication with certificates but that adds a lot of overhead. Sometimes AES authentication makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Devise uses BCrypt. You need modify the encrypted_password field in the USERS table and put a new encrypted password.

You can generate a new encrypted password in this website:
http://www.bcrypt-generator.com/

Comment: If you are trying to have an easy way to auth into a users account to debug something this is a great way! Just remember to save their encrypted password to save back in when you are done.       :: Steps I took - u = User.find(:ID) - u.encrypted_password - store password somewhere - u.password = "new_password" - u.save - debug issue - u.encrypted_password = :stored_encrypted_password: - u.save

Answer (score 0):

I think those passwords are one way encrypted: you can take a password provided by user, encrypt it and compare it to the encrypted one in the database (if matches - successful attempt). But un-encrypting the one in database is not possible, so that noone can get all passwords out. It is a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable...

  def verify_password?(password)
    encryptor_class = Devise::Encryptors.const_get(Devise.encryptor.to_s.classify)
    encryptor_digest = encryptor_class.digest(password, Devise.stretches, self.password_salt, Devise.pepper)
    encryptor_digest == self.encrypted_password
  end
end
```