# How can I enter user page from active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm using active admin in my rails application.

I want to enter user's account page from active admin page because I want to check what the user exactly is seeing.

I thought that I can decrypt devise encrypted password, but I found out that I cannot do that [Rails Devise, how to unencrypt a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555934/rails-devise-how-to-unencrypt-a-password)

I tried entering the site by using the encrypted password, but I couldn't.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If it so important, you can copy encrypted password from db and paste own encrypted password for this user. You can do it via `rails c`. After your actions rewrite password again. But it is a bad way. You must write some tests for your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the Devise Wiki How to :
    [How To: Sign in as another user if you are an admin](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin)

The proposed solution replaces the current user in session, so I think you'll be signed out of ActiveAdmin.