# Password not getting stored for a model with same table, but different structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a model called User, which has first_name, last_name and password attributes. It is using Devise. Now I want to have another model called Receptionist, which shares the same table of User. User can add Receptionists.

Here is my code

```
 class Receptionist < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessor :password_confirmation
    self.table_name = "users"
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id' #source: :doctor
 end

     class User < ApplicationRecord
        devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
       has_many :receptionists, :class_name => 'Receptionist', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :receptionists, allow_destroy: true
     end
```

In the update method - I have this

```
user = User.new(get_params)
user.save


  def get_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name,
         receptionists_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :_destroy]
      )
 end
```

Here is the api call

```
{
    "auth_token": "TMERW-fhNroA9La9iUSX",
    "user": {
        "receptionists_attributes": {
            "0": {
                "first_name": "reception 1",
                "last_name": "g",
                "email": "xx@gmail.com",
                "password": "xxxxx",
                "password_confirmation": "xxxx"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the record of the recptionist is getting saved, except the password. password is getting stored as nil. can any one please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: Remove `attr_accessor :password` and
    `attr_accessor :password_confirmation`

Comment: Then I am getting unknown attribute password error

Comment: Then password is not in the db

Comment: `user` table usually don't have `password` column, because you should never store the password in clear text

Comment: Okay you are right .. then where the password is stored?

Comment: Do you want the receptionists to be able to sign in?  The password is stored in a field called `encrypted_password`

Comment: Okay the encrypted password for the record that is created by the user is showing as " " @SteveTurczyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable` to `Receptionist` model.

You need to remove

```
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessor :password_confirmation
```

because it will override devise's methods to set `encrypted_password`. And `attr` generate by `attr_accessor` won't save to database, so when out of the lifecycle, it becomes `nil`.

And the `devise` won't directly save raw password to database, it will encrypt the `password` and save it in `encrypted_password` column, so you can't extract the `password`, you can only verify if a `password` is valid, like

```
user.valid_password?('12345678')
```

for the encrypt algorithm, check [Rails Devise, how to unencrypt a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555934/rails-devise-how-to-unencrypt-a-password)

Comment: add `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable` to `Receptionist` model also

Comment: please add this comment in your answer .. I am just about the write the same answer .. as I figured out .. thanks anyways ..

Comment: @gates although it's working, but have to say, 2 model use same tables, it seems wired. you might check `acts_as_tree` or other gems which enhance  activerecord, think about if you really have to do this way. or at least has model override.